# How do I run an desktop executable file on Windows over SSH?

Tags: cygwin, desktop, openssh

Here's my situation:
I have Machine A - Linux Box, and Machine B - Windows Box using Cygwin and OpenSSH.

Currently, I can ssh between the two machines, and run programs. There is this program that I need to run on the Windows Machine that will Control the Desktop (some mouse clicks and such).

I need to be able to ssh to the Windows Machine from my Linux machine (done already) and run the program. When I do this, the program just hangs up. I can see the program in the System Processes on Windows, however it is doing nothing. When I call the program on Cygwin on the Windows machine, it runs flawlessly.

My question:

Is there a way to run the executable program on the Windows Machine that controls its Desktop environment - run it remotely over SSH?

PS: I have tried on the Windows Machine to go to Services > Cygwin sshd > Log on > Allow Services to interact with desktop. However, when this is checked I can't get the Cygwin sshd service started.

Comment: You don't get the same environment when you ssh in as when you log in or run from the machine. try running "ssh which my_program.exe" to see fi you're running what you think you are.